# MoreEvents PayPal Transaction Failed

Tags: ee2

We have just started to reuse our renewals templates for 2016. Last year everything worked successfully and we processed thousands of transactions. I have just carried out a few tests and i'm getting an error in the models/more_event_cp_data.php program.

[image: Transaction Log]

Can anyone identify the likely cause?

The code in question is as follows:-

---

```
public function get_event_tx($event_tx_id='')
{
    $this->EE->db->where("id", $event_tx_id);
    $q = $this->EE->db->get("moreevents_tx")->row_array();

    $c = MoreEventCurrency::get($q['currency']);

    $q['amount_paid'] = $c['htmlEntity'].number_format($q['amount_paid'], 2);
    $q['price'] = $c['htmlEntity'].number_format($q['price'], 2);

    $str = "<ul>";
    foreach(unserialize($q['attendees']) as $attendee){
        $str .= "<li>". $attendee['name']."</li>";
    }
    $str .= "</ul>";

    $q['attendees'] = $str;


    $q['raw_response'] = "<pre>".print_r(unserialize($q['raw_response']), TRUE)."</pre>";
    $q['last_activity'] = date("r", $q['last_activity'] );

    unset($q['success_template']);
    unset($q['fail_template']);


    return $q;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have an event which has no attendees, and the code assumes that each event will *have* attendees, hence the error.

Try replacing:

```
$str = "<ul>";
foreach(unserialize($q['attendees']) as $attendee){
    $str .= "<li>". $attendee['name']."</li>";
}
$str .= "</ul>";

$q['attendees'] = $str;
```

With:

```
if($attendees = unserialize($q['attendees'])
{    
    $str = "<ul>";
    foreach($attendees as $attendee){
        $str .= "<li>". $attendee['name']."</li>";
    }
    $str .= "</ul>";

    $q['attendees'] = $str;
}
```